# Does my UoW class need to implement IDisposable if my BaseUow already implements it?

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, idisposable, unit-of-work

I have created a base class for my Unit of Work called BaseUoW that inherits IDisposable like so:

```
public class BaseUoW : IDisposable
{
}
```

My question is... If i create class called UserUoW for example that inherits my BaseUoW does the UserUoW need to implement IDisposable or will it be handled by my BaseUow

```
public class BaseUoW : IBaseUoW
{
}
```

Or

```
public class BaseUoW : IBaseUoW, IDisposable
{
}
```

IBaseUoW

```
public interface IBaseUoW
{
    virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);
    void Commit();
}
```

Comment: Pictures of code?  No.  Please, no.

Comment: answer depends entirely on IBaseUoW interface which is not shown

Comment: I've removed your images and made them code. Please learn how to post and format questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks image police.

Comment: Note: duplicate is based on title of the post, code of the post *does not* support title's claim as `IBaseUoW` does not implement `IDisposable`. Please edit your post if duplicate does not answer your question to clarify what you are asking. (Consider adding comment to me with `@alexei`when you done editing so I can remove my duplicate vote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add it to the class declaration, unless you want to make it explicit for readability.

However, what you may need, is to add a `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){` method override to perform the child class' clean up tasks if there are any.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on the proper pattern to follow.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, this is only if you are truly extending from your base `BaseUoW` class.  Because your "pictures" show it implementing some other interface, not extending your base class in question.